# Less.js aggressively caching imported less files

Tags: javascript, css, caching, less

I'm running Less through JavaScript right now, with `less = { env: ‘development’ };`, and I have a primary file, called main.less, which houses all my `@import`, however none of my imported "children" .less files are updating, and appears to just be using the old cached styles.

Put a line of code into main.less, compiles. Remove it and put into nav.less, compiles main.less, and appears to yank nav.less from the cache. Ugh.

I've tried `less.refresh();`, and even tried `localStorage.clear();`, but nothing seems to change the outcome.

I feel so defeated by this.

Comment: Are you sure it's the Less script caching the compiled result and *not* the browser caching linked Less files?

Answer (score 1):

You said **localStorage.clear()** so you must be using less in browser. I tried to build an environment for this, and everything worked as expected. I used less option as below:

```
{
      filename: "./test/main.less",
       useFileCache: false
}
```

The html file is as below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="blackmiaool's page">
    <meta name="author" content="blackmiaool">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="js/less.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="next">Next</button>
    <textarea id="output" placeholder="output" style="height:230px;width:230px;">
       
   </textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log(less);

        function update() {
            $.get("./test/main.less", function(mainFileContent) {
                less.render(mainFileContent, {
                        filename: "./test/main.less",
                        useFileCache: false
                    })
                    .then(function(output) {
                        $("#output").val(output.css);
                        console.log(output);
                    })
            });
        }
        update();
        $("#next").on("click", update);

    </script>
</body>
```

main.less:

```
@import "./nav.less";
h5 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: aliceblue;
}
```

nav.less:

```
h4 {
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

You can download a demo here(you should deploy it yourself): http://blackmiaool.com/test_less_demo.zip

#### How did I try to reproduce the problem

1. Open the page
2. Open the **main.less**
3. Delete the line `color: aliceblue;`
4. Save the **main.less**
5. Open the **nav.less**
6. Intert the line `color: aliceblue;` into the second line.
7. Save the **nav.less**
8. Click the "Next" button

The output changed from

```
h4 {
    font-size: 50px;
}
h5 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: aliceblue;
}
```

to

```
h4 {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: aliceblue;
}
h5 {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

## What if the file request is cached?

Less's file request code(from [less](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/24523c6a869a2337a6ca3e9e10eb1a06eeca5fa7/lib/less-browser/file-manager.js#L24)):

```
FileManager.prototype.doXHR = function doXHR(url, type, callback, errback)     {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var async = options.isFileProtocol ? options.fileAsync : true;

    if (typeof xhr.overrideMimeType === 'function') {
        xhr.overrideMimeType('text/css');
    }
    logger.debug("XHR: Getting '" + url + "'");
    xhr.open('GET', url, async);
```

According to this snippet, less use `xhr` to get the file(of course). So we can try to hack the `XMLHttpRequest` to change the url:

```
var preOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    if (url.match(/\.less$/)) {
        url += `?time=${Date.now()}`;
        args[1]=url;
    }            
    return preOpen.apply(this, args);
}
```

[Demo](http://blackmiaool.com/soa/42999194/test_less.html)

And open the "Network" tab to check the less files requests.

Comment: Wondering: if `useFileCache` is true, how would one clear out that cache? I ran into some issue where Browser Caching interfered for some reason.

Comment: This may need diving into the source code. @MichaelStum

Comment: Well, I just found that you are the one who provided bounty. The documentation says that the cache is stored in localStorage, and OP said that `localStorage.clear();` is useless for this. So what's your condition? Why did you refer **Browser Caching**? @MichaelStum

Comment: It's time to sleep for chinese. If you describe your need more detailedly, I will try to solve it tomorrow.

Comment: @MichaelStum Does localStorage.clear(); work for you?

Comment: Found it. Yeah, `localStorage.clear();` was indeed doing the trick. Turns out that something unrelated to less didn't work for me (basically, .less files were served from a different IIS website, which did some super-aggressive caching (304 not modified/etag nonsense), so less.js couldn't see the new files)

Comment: I updated the answer to handle the browser caching things. Wish it can help you. @MichaelStum